# `Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll` is unable to load

Tags: visual-studio, winui-3

I am getting an exception in my WinUI3 app that `Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll` is unable to load.  I have included Microsoft.UI.Xaml and Microsoft.Graphics.Win2D in nuget.

```
System.DllNotFoundException
  HResult=0x80131524
  Message=Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)
  Source=TibraUI
  StackTrace:
   at TibraUI.Program.XamlCheckProcessRequirements()
   at TibraUI.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Bryan\src\tibra\Tibra\TibraUI\obj\x64\Debug\net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\App.g.i.cs:line 28
```

Windows Version 21H1
Build 19043.1348

My App.xaml

```
<Application
    x:Class="TibraUI.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TibraUI">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />
                <!-- Other merged dictionaries here -->
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!-- Other app resources here -->
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues/1762

Comment: FWIW I am seeing the same error and the link provided by Hans refers to a now closed thread that does not offer a solution - the suggested install of the VC redist does not work for me.

Comment: A solution that seemed to work for me was to select the template with two projects, i.e. the one with the separate packager project (WAP). As long as you have the packager project selected as startup project, it seems to work. Setting the 'real' project as startup results in the same error. Mind you you have to set your machine to developer mode.

Comment: @Rno That didn't work for me unfortunately

Comment: @BAR sorry to hear that. I am completely new to this so have very little to offer you. I created a new working boilerplate WinUI3 project and put in on GitHub, perhaps browsing that code or cloning it may give you some insights. https://github.com/arnovb-github/EmptyWinUI

Comment: Had the same error, in my case it occurred when trying to create & run an unpackaged  winui3 app.  It was fixed by adding the following property to the project file: `<WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>true</WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>`

Answer (score 18):

Run the package as the startup project. It's not intuitive, but the main project is not meant to run.

This answer only applies to those who created a project that included a package project.

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: I only have one project

Comment: Are you sure, maybe there is another entry in your solution "{project name} (Package)"? If yes, try to start this one.

Comment: Yep that was it. Just set the package project as the startup project and hit run. You will see in the progress bar of vs it "deploy",

Answer (score 14):

In the app project file, inside the main PropertyGroup, add `<WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>true</WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>` as shown below.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
    <RootNamespace>EPicker</RootNamespace>
    <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
    <Platforms>x86;x64;arm64</Platforms>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x86;win10-x64;win10-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <PublishProfile>win10-$(Platform).pubxml</PublishProfile>
    <UseWinUI>true</UseWinUI>
    <EnableMsixTooling>true</EnableMsixTooling>
    <WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>true</WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Well, ok, this fixes the app startup, [but breaks other stuff](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues/3439). (Why is WinUI3 so buggy )

Comment: This fixed it for me as well!!  Kept getting ```Windows.UI.Xaml``` can't be loaded as an error in event viewer.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the issue in the following way:

I created a Uno WinUI 3 .NET 6 project using dotnet new unoapp-winui-net6 from the command prompt. I had to update the Windows.Desktop.csproj reference from:

```
<ItemGroup> 
    <FrameworkReference Update="Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.Ref" RuntimeFrameworkVersion="10.0.18362.16" /> 
    <FrameworkReference Update="Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.Ref" TargetingPackVersion="10.0.18362.16" /> 
</ItemGroup>
```

to:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Update="Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.Ref" RuntimeFrameworkVersion="10.0.19041.22" />
    <FrameworkReference Update="Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.Ref" TargetingPackVersion="10.0.19041.22" />
</ItemGroup>
```

and in the Windows.Package.wapproj, I updated

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK" Version="[1.0.0-experimental1]">
        <IncludeAssets>build</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

to

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK" Version="[1.0.0]">
        <IncludeAssets>build</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

(see also https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/discussions/7617)

In the Configuration Manager in Visual Studio 2022 Preview 1.1, I then had to change the platform for Windows.Desktop to x64 (was x86). Windows.package should also be x64.

I set the Windows.Package project as the startup project. I could build and start the application without the error.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved adding a launchSettings.json with:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "Windows Machine": {
      "commandName": "MsixPackage",
      "nativeDebugging": false
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem for "Blank App, Packaged with WAP (WinUI 3 in Desktop)".
I need to build both packages:

- "signed package"
- "unsigned lunch app via .exe".

By default you can build only signed packaged. But simply add `<WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>true</WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>` into csproj in app project, not in Package project.
Now you can build app that launch via .exe.
When you need build signed package, just comment `WindowsAppSDKSelfContained`.

Full .csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
    <RootNamespace>ButLoaderWin32</RootNamespace>
    <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
    <Platforms>x86;x64;ARM64</Platforms>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x86;win10-x64;win10-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <UseWinUI>true</UseWinUI>
    <!-- comment WindowsAppSDKSelfContained if you want packaged app for WinStore, uncomment if you want unpackaged app without certification-->
    <WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>true</WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK" Version="1.3.230602002" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools" Version="10.0.22621.755" />
    <Manifest Include="$(ApplicationManifest)" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```